# Compete understanding of encodings and character sets

Tags: unicode, character-encoding

Can anybody tell me where to find some clear introduction to character sets, encodings and everything releted to these things?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can think of two articles:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) - the legendary article from our Joel Spolsky.
- [Unicode - How to get characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) - more practical and targeted on Java webdevelopment (as per your question history, you seem to be doing Java webdevelopment).

Comment: OP - *after* you read these, look at other references if you need to.

Comment: Tim Bray: [Characters versus bytes](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2003/04/26/UTF)